# Is there a tokenizer function written in C that can do what boost::escaped_list_separator does?

Tags: c, boost

I am looking for a stand alone tokenizer written in C that can parse and split strings based on user supplied character separator such as tabs, semi colons, commas etc. 
Similar to what this boost library function does 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/tokenizer/escaped_list_separator.htm 
The tokens may be double quoted and the separators may be embedded, empty tokens are not skipped

Comment: No, but it's fairly easy to write one yourself. Simple state machine should do the trick.

Comment: @Tony: `strtok` doesn't support escaping.

Comment: @Tony The Tiger Yes, I have looked at strtok and it can't do what that boost function does. Not even close. I don't have sufficient C knowledge to adapt strtok to achieve what I want

Comment: @Billy ONeal I am sure it is easy for c experts on SO that's why I am asking. If you have written one such function please point me where to find it.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `c++`?

Comment: @molita: Stack Overflow is not a "give me the code please" website.

Comment: @molita: It _can_ do what "that Boost function" does _in conjunction with some more work_. You will have to get used to the idea right now that no _single_ C function will automagically do the entire thing for you. C functions are pretty low-level, so you're basically going to be re-inventing the Boost function using some C functions as a basis.

Comment: molita: You need to be able to write simple things like this yourself. @Tomalak: It's no longer tagged C++.

Comment: @Billy: Again, thanks for editing, but I want the OP to learn to get the tagging right in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) in `string.h`. You certainly will have to adapt it to manage specifics. As it is C, be careful about null-terminated strings.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "cstring" -- in C you need to be looking for `<string.h>`.

Comment: `s/cstring/string.h/` please. This is C, not C++.